# RabbitMQ - How do i get old message that has been published?

Tags: java, rabbitmq, messagebroker

Lets say the publisher and first subscriber has been starting, After one minute i start the second subscriber, but the second subscriber cannot get the old message a minute before, how do i get the old message for the second subcriber ?
right now i used this pattern [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvPjW.jpg)

Publisher And First Subcriber start at 11:28AM
First subsciber has messages like this:

["M1", "M2", "M3"]

And then second subscriber start at 11:30AM

First subsciber has messages like this:

["M1", "M2", "M3", "M4", "M5", "M6"]

Second subsciber has messages like this:

["M4", "M5", "M6"]

How do the second subscriber get old messages and have the same messages like first subscriber ?

Comment: Are you persisting the message somewhere in the Broker? My understanding is that if the message has been consumed by one subscriber, it cannot be consumed again. For the fan-out, I think the broker will publish to all the available subscribers, only. In your case, there was only one subscriber.

Comment: Yes, i have been persisting all of messages, as I know persisting the message is to pretending the message disappear when the server restart. I edited my questions to make it clear.

Comment: I think, for this scenario, you may have to send an event to the publisher about the newly added queue, along with a log of all the message ids that have been sent previously. After that, the publisher can send the history of messages and broker can redirect them to the new queue.  There are associated concerns, however. As far as I know, this is not how we may want to use the MQs. Use them only for the immediate transport of Messages.

Comment: I think, I should try to use kafka for this scenario. Thank you very much for your answer @Amal